# How can I install armv8 kernel on a armv7 distro (e.g kali for raspberry pi 3)?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kali-linux, raspberry-pi, arm

I've installed Kali Linux on raspberry pi 3.

RPI3`s CPU architecture is armv8 but Kali is for armv7

Is it possible to install/compile armv8 kernel for the pi? How can I do that?

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Raspbian on the rpi v3; most Linux distributions can boot on the raspberry pi.

One option is to use Debian, of which Raspbian is a derivative. Deborah has an armv8 version (called 'arm64') that you can install on your raspberry pi 3.

Comment: I know that and as I said I don't have raspbian installed on it. I have Kali Linux which is for armv7 I want to install armv8 kernel on it

Comment: Whoops, I'm an idiot, sorry. I don't know if there is an armv8 version of Kali, buy I do think you can run a 32 bit userland on a 64 bit arm kernel